# IPOJO Component is not exposing service properly

Tags: apache-karaf, apache-felix, ipojo

i have ipojo component like

```
@Component(immediate = true)
@Provides
public class MyComponent implements MyService
{

@Override
    public boolean islock()
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

when i deploy in karaf with below command

```
bundle:install -s mvn:com.my.osgi/mycomponent/0.0.1
```

if i do service:list at karaf console it shows output like

```
[org.apache.felix.ipojo.Factory] 
    -------------------------------- 
     component.class = com.my.osgi.mycomponent 
     component.description = factory name="com.my.osgi.mycomponent" 
bundle="77" state="valid" implementation-class="com.my.osgi.mycomponent" 
            requiredhandlers list="[org.apache.felix.ipojo:properties, 
org.apache.felix.ipojo:callback, org.apache.felix.ipojo:provides, 
org.apache.felix.ipojo:architect 
    ure]" 
            missinghandlers list="[]" 
            provides specification="com.my.osgi.mycomponent" 
            inherited interfaces="[com.my.osgi.mycomponent]" 
superclasses="[]" 
     component.providedServiceSpecifications = [com.my.osgi.mycomponent] 
     factory.name = com.my.osgi.mycomponent 
     factory.state = 1 
     service.bundleid = 77 
     service.id = 153 
     service.pid = com.my.osgi.mycomponent 
     service.scope = singleton
```

But i am expecting like below,

```
[com.my.osgi.mycomponent] 
    ----------------------------------------------------- 
    instance.name = mycomponent.3c2c91a5-4c28-46c3-a08e-1470192ef353 
     service.bundleid = 76 
     service.factoryPid = com.my.osgi.mycomponent 
     service.id = 397 
     service.pid = 
com.my.osgi.mycomponent.3c2c91a5-4c28-46c3-a08e-1470192ef353 
     service.scope = bundle
```

What i am doing wrong? I am building with maven.

**EDIT:**
One observation as this bundle working in one bigger application where when this get deploy logs are

```
2018-07-17T12:03:50,011 | DEBUG | [iPOJO] pool-1-thread-1 | my-component | 38 - com.my.osgi.my-component  - 1.0.3 | ServiceEvent REGISTERED - [org.apache.felix.ipojo.architecture.Architecture] - com.my.osgi.my-component
2018-07-17T12:03:50,021 | DEBUG | [iPOJO] pool-1-thread-1 | my-component | 38 - com.my.osgi.my-component  - 1.0.3 | ServiceEvent REGISTERED - [com.my.osgi.my-component]                         - com.my.osgi.my-component
2018-07-17T12:03:50,021 | DEBUG | [iPOJO] pool-1-thread-1 | my-component | 38 - com.my.osgi.my-component  - 1.0.3 | ServiceEvent MODIFIED -   [com.my.osgi.my-component]                         - com.my.osgi.my-component
2018-07-17T12:03:50,021 | DEBUG | [iPOJO] pool-1-thread-1 | my-component | 38 - com.my.osgi.my-component  - 1.0.3 | ServiceEvent MODIFIED -   [com.my.osgi.my-component]                         - com.my.osgi.my-component
2018-07-17T12:03:50,021 | DEBUG | [iPOJO] pool-1-thread-1 | my-component | 38 - com.my.osgi.my-component  - 1.0.3 | ServiceEvent MODIFIED -   [com.my.osgi.my-component]                         - com.my.osgi.my-component
2018-07-17T12:03:50,021 | DEBUG | [iPOJO] pool-1-thread-1 | my-component | 38 - com.my.osgi.my-component  - 1.0.3 | ServiceEvent REGISTERED - [org.apache.felix.ipojo.Factory] - com.my.osgi.my-component
```

but in my case its only two lines

```
2018-07-17T11:45:43,624 | DEBUG | [iPOJO] pool-1-thread-1 | my-component  | 11 - com.my.osgi.my-component - 2.0.4.SNAPSHOT | ServiceEvent REGISTERED - [org.apache.felix.ipojo.extender.TypeDeclaration] - com.my.osgi.my-component
2018-07-17T11:45:43,654 | DEBUG | [iPOJO] pool-1-thread-1 | my-component  | 11 - com.my.osgi.my-component - 2.0.4.SNAPSHOT | ServiceEvent REGISTERED - [org.apache.felix.ipojo.Factory] - com.my.osgi.my-component
```

So what this architecture doing and what got modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the @Instantiate annotation on your component class. Alternatively, you can use:

- iPOJO Factory service (http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-ipojo/apache-felix-ipojo-userguide/ipojo-advanced-topics/ipojo-factory-service.html)
- the Config Admin (http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-ipojo/apache-felix-ipojo-userguide/ipojo-advanced-topics/combining-ipojo-and-configuration-admin.html)
- A class annotated with @Configuration